# I have a code, where json data is retrieved, Now I want handle different exceptions

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have included JsonException.
Do we have any exception for no response, different key or value and different JSON structure?
I am using kotlin in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONException includes these cases:

```
Attempts to parse or construct malformed documents
Use of null as a name
Use of numeric types not available to JSON, such as NaNs or infinities.
Lookups using an out of range index or nonexistent name
Type mismatches on lookups
```

If you get JSON from network, you should handle other exceptions like IOException. That is not related to JSON, and is not covered in JSONException.